# mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf and vector struct type

Tags: pyspark, databricks, mlflow

My *PySpark* dataset contains categorical data.

To train a model on this data, I followed this [example notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/binary-classification.html). Especially, see the *Preprocess Data* section for the encoding part.

I now need to use this model somewhere else; hence, I followed *Databricks* recommendation to save and load this model.

It's working fine with *Pandas* (cf. code below).

```
logged_model = 'runs:/e905f5759d434a1391bbe1e54a2b/best-model'

# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(logged_model)

# Predict on a Pandas DataFrame.
import pandas as pd
loaded_model.predict(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

However the dataframe is to big to be converted to *Pandas*. Hence I need to make it work in *Spark*:

```
import mlflow
logged_model = 'runs:/e905f5759d434a131bbe1e54a2b/best-model'

# Load model as a Spark UDF.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri=logged_model)

# Predict on a Spark DataFrame.
df.withColumn('predictions', loaded_model(*columns)).collect()
```

But this snippet is producing:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported data type: struct&lt;type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array&lt;int&gt;,values:array&lt;double&gt;&gt;
```

My feeling is that the udf doesn't accept this type of data as input.
Is there a way to fix it ?
Another solution ?

Comment: a little late, but don't you need loaded_model(*df.columns) instead of *columns. Columns in your code isn't defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `mlflow.spark.load_model`?

I'm having a very similar issue over here, but but using the spark method. I tried using the `mlflow.spark.load_model('runs:/run-id/my-model')` method and I got this weird error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/tmp/mlflow/weird-id-folder'
```

Searching for the docs, I see the problem that we are facing (which seems to be different), seems to be a signature problem.

According with other part of the [docs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#model-signature) we have that the signature logged with the model will help to define what type of input the model has. The problem for me here is that my input is a Spark Sparse Vector -- which is not supported... Right now I'm trying to convert that into a column-based signature.

Have you tried something like this?

---

UPDATE:

I would like to add that in my case adding the signature did solve the problem. All I did was ignore the vectors and consider only the input data and output data.

I took a look into the notebook, but haven't seen any mlflow logs, anyway, I do suppose you are logging your experiment according to [this](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/mlflow/tracking.html#log-runs-to-a-notebook-or-workspace-experiment) and using the `mlflow.spark` flavor.

If so, consider using all your data transformation and model fit in the same pipeline, using `from pyspark.ml import Pipeline`. Before logging the model, consider going under signature and registering the model schema.

```
import mlflow.spark
from mlflow.models.signature import infer_signature

with mlflow.start_run():
    [...]
    # executing train & test pipelines:
    model = pipeline.fit(train_features) # training model
    predictions = model.transform(test_features) # testing model
    train_signature = train_features.select('input_data') # ignores all other features created on the pipeline
    prediction_signature = predictions.select('input_data', 'prediction') # ignores all other features created on the training pipeline 
    signature = infer_signature(train_signature, prediction_signature) # register model schema
    mlflow.spark.log_model(model, 'transactions-classification', signature=signature) # logging model to mlflow
    [...]
```

After logging the model to the experiment, in a different notebook, you can use the load_model function as:

```
# importing model
import mlflow.spark
model_path = 'runs:/run-id'
model = mlflow.spark.load_model(model_path)
```

And it will work! :D

Comment: I am running in the same issues that I cannot infer the schema from a features vector. Your `input_data` could be multiple columns right? All before any processing is done? Does that mean that is saved with the logged model and I can input the raw data?

Comment: input_data is one col and it is the raw data. The other processing features are done inside the model and output is the prediction. It will follow the pipeline schema - you can see that inside databricks models. Input schema can be multiple cols, but it need to have the input_col as one of the cols, others will be ignored.